# Вывод из mssql с помощью sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте запутался с синтаксисом
вот есть блок в который нужно вывести значение из одной ячейки в таблице.

```
$sql = "SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent WHERE Pname=$Fname";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
echo $stmt;
```

Имя строчки откуда вытаскивать определяется по имени текущего открытого файла, которое заносится в переменную, это важно.

на выходе получаю вот это:

```
SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent WHERE Pname=mopr
```

вместо содержания ячейки, буду рад, если подскажите

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при выводе из mssql через php (sqlsrv)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598521/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-mssql-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-php-sqlsrv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pname имеет, вероятно, строковый тип? тогда вставляемый в строку запроса литерал должен быть обрамлён кавычками.

```
$sql = "SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent WHERE Pname='$Fname'";
```

Comment: не помогло :С
 $query = "SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent WHERE Pname='$Fname'";
      $result = sqlsrv_query ($conn,$query);
      $myrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($result);
 echo $myrow;

 ?> 


ошибка та же

Comment: PHP Warning:  sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\technet\mopr.php on line 24

Comment: **@qaz qaz** Для меня загадка выражение "ошибка та же" - в исходном сообщении НЕТ никакого сообщения об ошибке. Есть только результат, который отличается от ожидаемого (хотя я не понимаю, почему - для приведённого там кода он правильный). А чтобы понять, почему запрос не выполняется - включите после sqlsrv_query проверку на ошибку (проверку $result на FALSE) и вывод ошибки.

Comment: я немного тупанул :D
вот листинг:
$sql = "SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent WHERE Pname='$Fname'";
      $result = sqlsrv_query ($conn,$sql);
     
    
 echo  $result;

но при обработке теперь не выводит вообще ничего :С

Answer (score 0):

```
    function NumRows($query) {
        return mssql_num_rows($query);
    }


    function FetchArray($query) {
        return mssql_fetch_array($query);
    }

        $Result = $DB->Query('SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent WHERE Pname = $Fname order by ConnectTM ASC');

    if ($DB->NumRows($Result) == 0) {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><center>no!</center></td></tr>';
    }

    while($Info = $DB->FetchArray($Result)) {
        ++$Count;

        $GetInfo = $DB->FetchRow($DB->Query("SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent WHERE Name = '$Fname[0]'"));
        $Name = $GetInfo[0];

        echo '<td align="center">'.$Name.'</td>
            ';
    }
```

Comment: делайте, пожалуйста, более развернутые ответы. Как Ваш код связан с кодом в вопросе? Что происходит у ТС и почему он по-Вашему наблюдает такое поведение...Что делает Ваш код и т.д. и т.п.