# Ошибка при выводе из mssql через php (sqlsrv)

Tags: php, sql-server, веб-программирование

Привет всем, вот кусок кода, в котором должно происходить следующее:
чекается имя файла (текущего) и его имя сохраняется в переменную 
Fname
далее происходит запрос в БД в котором надо вытащить значение определенной ячейки в строчке, орентируясь на ячейку в той-же строчке под названием Pname которая содержит то, что хранится в переменной Pname

```
  $query= "SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent
                  WHERE Pname='$Fname'";
                  $result = sqlsrv_query ($conn,$query);
                  $myrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($result);
 echo $myrow;
 ?>
```

при отработке скрипта сыпется такая ошибка :

```
PHP Warning:  sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\technet\mopr.php on line 25
```

строчка 25:

```
 $myrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($result);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто. `sqlsrv_query ($conn,$query);` завершается с ошибкой и возвращает `false`, а не результирующий набор.

Используйте `sqlsrv_errors` для просмотра возникшей ошибки.

Comment: не могу собразить как сделать то, что мне нужно :С если убираю выборку по WHERE, то все как-бы работает но не совсем, возвращается Resours id  #6, как бы мне вытащить значение из ячейки ориентируясь на переменную

Comment: @qazqaz дополнил ответ